# Renaming a directory in svn

Tags: svn, rename

I had a folder structure like this:

```
A/B/C/hello.txt
```

I used svn mv to rename A to Z:

```
Z/B/C/hello.txt
```

I then made some modifications to hello.txt. Now, svn status gives:

```
D    A/B/C/hello.txt
A+   Z
M+   Z/B/C/hello.txt
```

When I try to commit, I get the following error message:

```
'Z/B/C' is not under version control and is not part of the commit, yet its child 'Z/B/C/hello.txt' is part of the commit
```

Comment: See this question, the accepted answer may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941291/a-sane-way-to-rename-a-directory-in-subversion-working-copy

Comment: Try changing the folder name, commit that change, and then make changes to the files themselves

Comment: That post suggests making sure you're totally up to date before doing the rename, which I was.

Comment: So basically, the solution is to do this in two separate commits since svn doesn't directly support these operations in a single commit. Would that be a correct assessment? If so, I'll make it the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 10):

```
Commands and their output to rename SVN folder in above example are shown below:
# svn mv A Z
A         Z
D         A/B/C/hello.txt
D         A/B/C
D         A/B
D         A
# ls
A  Z
# rm -rf A
#ls
Z
# svn st
D       A
A  +    Z
# svn ci -m "Commit message."
Deleting       source/A
Adding         source/Z

Committed revision 307.
# svn st
# ls -R
.:
Z

./Z:
B

./Z/B:
C

./Z/B/C:
hello.txt
```

Comment: Or you can do it in the svn server without checking out.

Answer (score 0):

To directly rename a directory / folder on the server, just use `svn mv` with the server URL, e.g.:

```
svn mv https://your-svn/old-name https://your-svn/new-name
```

In fish shell, you can even make this shorter:

```
svn mv https://your-svn/{old-name,new-name}
```